# UIRefreshControl bounce

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

I have implemented a pull to refresh control using `UIRefreshControl` with a `UICollectionView`. It works well, however, when I pull the collection view beyond the point where it initiates new data fetch, collection view jumps down by what seems to be navigation bar (plus status bar) height, i.e. the motion is not smooth.

I first thought this might be because of iOS7 content offsets, but this happens in iOS6 as well.

Any ideas what can be wrong or what I should check?

Comment: UIRefreshControl adjusts the `contentInset` property, which is present in iOS 6 as well.  Do you have any code that manually adjusts this property?

Comment: No, I don't fiddle with contentInset in this viewController at all

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout in storyBoard ?

Comment: I'm using neither AutoLayout, nor StoryBoards

Answer (score 0):

From UIRefreshControl reference:

> Because the refresh control is specifically designed for use in a
>   table view that's managed by a table view controller, using it in a
>   different context can result in undefined behavior.

Basically, saying that it will play nicely only when used inside UITableViewController. When used elsewhere, this weird bounce occurs.